# Range bar chart multiple zone colors Flutter

Tags: flutter, charts, flutter-dependencies, mpandroidchart

I would like to find a library on flutter to have this type of rendering, with a return callback in case of click on the selected area. Any idea?

[image: Range bar according hours]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i used [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter)

the type of chart used is : [Stacked Fill Color Bar Chart](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/stacked_fill_color)

in my example : i needed just one bar, u will find the callBack in `changedListener`, `strokeWidthPxFn` is used to make white border's selected area

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

class StackedHorizontalBarChart extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => StackedHorizontalBarChartState();
}

class StackedHorizontalBarChartState extends State<StackedHorizontalBarChart>{

  List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  int count = 0;
  int selected = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // For horizontal bar charts, set the [vertical] flag to false.
    seriesList = _createSampleData(5 + count);

    return new charts.BarChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: false,
      //barGroupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.stacked,
      vertical: false,
      selectionModels: [
        charts.SelectionModelConfig (
          changedListener: (charts.SelectionModel model) {
            //final selectedDatum = model.selectedDatum;
            //SeriesDatum s = selectedDatum[model.selectedSeries[0].seriesIndex];

            print (model.selectedSeries[0].id);
            selected = model.selectedSeries[0].seriesIndex;
            print (selected);


            //count += 10;
            setState(() {

            });
          },
        ),
      ],
      // Configure a stroke width to enable borders on the bars.
      defaultRenderer: new charts.BarRendererConfig(
          groupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.stacked
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Create series list with multiple series
  List<charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>> _createSampleData(i1) {
    final desktopSalesData = [
      new OrdinalSales('2014', i1),
    ];

    final tableSalesData = [
      new OrdinalSales('2014', 25),
    ];

    final mobileSalesData = [
      new OrdinalSales('2014', 10),
    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
        id: 'Desktop',
        domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year, // X
        measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales, // Y
        data: desktopSalesData,
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.white,
        fillColorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault.lighter,
        strokeWidthPxFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => selected == 0 ? 5 : 0,
      ),
      new charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
        id: 'Tablet',
        measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: tableSalesData,
        fillColorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault,
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.white,
        domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        strokeWidthPxFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => selected == 1 ? 5 : 0,
      ),
      new charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
        id: 'Mobile',
        domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: mobileSalesData,
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.white,
        fillColorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.black,
        strokeWidthPxFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => selected == 2 ? 5 : 0,
      ),
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample ordinal data type.
class OrdinalSales {
  final String year;
  final int sales;

  OrdinalSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```